# Custom icon font from flaticon hosted on a different server doesn't work

Tags: css, fonts

I have downloaded a custom icon font from [Flaticon](https://flaticon.com) and tried to use it on a SaaS type shop. As I don't have access to the shop files, I've tried to host the font from an ftp server and tried to make it work on a demo page: [here](http://sklep1807322.home.pl). This works, but when I try to use something like [livewave](https://liveweave.com) all I get is a square instead of an icon.

on ftp server the css and font files are in the same directory and I used reletive links to the files in css, but the css itself is included with a global link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sklep1807322.home.pl/pub/flat_icons/font/flaticon.css">
```

the css file looks like this:

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Flaticon";
      src: url("./Flaticon.eot");
      src: url("./Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
           url("./Flaticon.woff2") format("woff2"),
           url("./Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
           url("./Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
           url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Flaticon";
        src: url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
      }
    }

    [class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
    [class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
      font-family: Flaticon;
            font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }

.flaticon-user:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon-shopping-bag:before { content: "\f101"; }
.flaticon-search:before { content: "\f102"; }
.flaticon-menu:before { content: "\f103"; }
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Access to font at 'https://sklep1807322.home.pl/pub/flat_icons/font/Flaticon.woff2' from origin 'https://liveweave.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

You need to fix the CORS Policy on the server where the Website will be to allow source: https://sklep1807322.home.pl/

It is working on http://sklep1807322.home.pl/ at the moment, as this is the SAME ORIGIN.

Comment: I can't find an option to edit .htacces on my SaaS shop, and I don't know if there is any way that my provider will allow this change. I'll try to contact them on mondey. In the mean time a followup question. Why the icon is visible on http:// but not on https://?